# jQuery selector statement selecting a select box option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

is there a selector for when an option selected in a select box like jQuery('select option[@selected=....] this were im confused is it just jQuery(select > option[@selected]) and also how do you test a an option in the jQuery selector statement that it's not the first option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look like this (note there's no `@`, this was removed in jQuery 1.3+):

```
jQuery("select option:selected")
```

If you wanted to get anything but the first, you can use [`:not(:first-child)`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/), like this:

```
jQuery("select option:selected:not(:first-child)")
//or...
jQuery("select option:gt(0):selected")
```

Though to get the value, you'd typically just want to call [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) directly on the `<select>`, like this:

```
jQuery("select").val()
```

Comment: so what about testing the select that is not the first option

Comment: @littleMan - that's the second line above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select option:selected");
```

or

```
$(this, "option:selected");
```

test not first option

```
$("select option:not(eq0)"); <---I think
```

Comment: Your third selector isn't correct..and wouldn't work to check for the selected status in combination.

Comment: you're last statement has me stumped is it a typeO mistake

Comment: @Nick Craver, he said check if its not the first option in the list, that has nothing to do with if it is selected or not.

Comment: Yes, but your code won't do that, not if he's trying to do both at the same time...your code (if it was correct) would get everything *but* the first option...that doesn't really help.  He's obviously trying to see if the *default* isn't selected.  When you factor that in, your selector combined with `:selected` would *never* return a result, since only one would be selected, and it would always be `:first`.